# increase the stack size in eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, linux, stack, out-of-memory, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to increase the stack size in eclipse CDT? I'm able to increase it using terminal in Ubuntu using the following statement :

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

But could not figure out the way to increase in eclipse CDT. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :** Example scenario -- I have an array of strings whose size is 2.5 million (using for storing unique names) as : `string names[2500000];`. But the program is unable to execute because there is not enough stack space (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: you should say what your issue really is. probably there is another well known solution which does not involve changing stack size

Comment: It is a very bad practice to declare an array of 2500000 `std::string`-s on the call stack. Use a `std::vector<std::string>` (and `resize(2500000)` it).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - yes, I appreciate your suggestion & I changed it to `std::vector<std::string> names;`. And allocating memory to heap solved the problem. But still that doesn't answer my question - is there a way to increase the stack size in eclipse CDT?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the linker's options you are using.